# Unable to encode csv to UTF-8

Tags: r

I am importing a csv and want to encode it to UTF-8 as some columns appear like this:

```
Comentario                                                                     Fecha      Mes   `Estaci\xf3n` Hotel        Marca
  <chr>                                                                          <date>     <chr> <chr>         <chr>        <chr>
1 "No todas las instalaciones del hotel se pudieron usar, estaban cerradas sin ~ 2020-02-01 feb.  "Invierno"    Sol Arona T~ Sol  
2 "Me he ido con un buen sabor de boca, y ganas de volver. Me ha sorprendido to~ 2019-11-01 nov.  "Oto\xf1o"    Sol Arona T~ Sol  
3 "Hotel normalito. Est\xe1 un poco viejo. Las habitaciones no tienen aire acon~ 2019-09-01 sep.  "Verano"      Sol Arona T~ Sol
```

I have tried the following:

```
df<- read.csv("SolArona.csv",  sep=",", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

But this returns Error in read_csv("SolArona.csv", sep = ",", encoding = "UTF-8") : 
  unused arguments (sep = ",", encoding = "UTF-8"). So, I have also tried doing the Encoding of each column:

```
df <-read_csv("SolArona.csv")
Encoding(df$Comentario)<-"UTF-8"
Encoding (df$Estaci\xf3n)<-"UTF-8"
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Can you try `df <- read.table("SolArona.csv",  sep=",", encoding = "UTF-8")` ?

Comment: It doesn't work, it gives an empty data.frame

Comment: What happens when you encode each column? You can do that programmatically using `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) {Encoding(x) <- "UTF-8";x})`

Comment: It returns this error:Error in gsub(reStrip, "", completions, perl = TRUE) : 
  input string 4 is invalid UTF-8

Comment: I think encoding lives insede the locale argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, insert another encoding if nescessary

```
library(readr)
df<- read_csv("SolArona.csv",",",locale = locale(encoding = "UTF-8"))
```